# Is there a way to obtain an api key from Viber?

Tags: api, viber

I have applied for public account twice in the last year and i never received an email from Viber that I have been approved for a public account. And now i don't even see the form you have to sign up in order to apply for a public account and get the api key from Viber. 
I want to be able to send messages to my clients using Viber, is there a way I can do that?
btw, I know you have to be a big company in order to have a Viber key, but in my country I saw that they are companies that are big as mine and have obtained a key and I can't and that drive me nuts :( Any help will be thankful.
I want to try and use this library - https://github.com/Bogdaan/viber-bot-php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked to Viber support team.

Comment: it is hard to find this information by the official way, thats why i have asked this question, here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viber Public Accounts are no longer supported and have been replaced with [Viber communities](https://www.viber.com/blog/2018-02-27/introducing-viber-communities/). Right now, there is no way how to programmatically send messages to Viber Communities. I think that you search for Viber Bots or Viber Service messages - notification messages replacing SMS.

In the first case, you can use https://partners.viber.com/ to register your account and get the api key.

Viber Service Messages are paid per message sent and available through several providers.

Comment: thanks for that, but i can't get now how to subscribe the users to the bot so i can find out the users id's and send them messages?

Comment: It's quite hard to discover your Viber bot. I think this is something Viber is working on. For the time being, you can use Viber links to share your bot: https://viber.me/{{URI}}. You can find more info at my project documentation: https://docs.amio.io/docs/viber-entry-points-links.

Comment: i found this url which suits me great https://developers.viber.com/docs/tools/deep-links/ ;)

Comment: the link you have provided gives me this error - `This account does not exist or has been removed`

Answer (score 1):

Simply got to [https://partners.viber.com/](http://partners.viber.com) and register new account.
You'll receive approve code to your viber app, and you'll be able to receive chat bot API key when  complete registration at yours viber APP.
[image]